# Do I pay the bank back if I shortsale?

Tags: mortgage, short-sale-property

I am confused about this.  If I still owe 350,000 on my house and it is valued at 270,000 and I short sell it for 270,000, would I need to pay the bank 80,000?  Are there scenarios where you don't have to pay the bank back?  I am unclear how this works.

Comment: If the bank writes off the balance due after the short sale, you will likely get a 1099 from the bank declaring that amount as income received by you.

Comment: Don't forget about any taxes owed. The current exemption ends at the end of 2012. Short sales can take months to get approved, the clock is ticking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any unpaid balance owed to the creditors is known as a deficiency. Technically you still owe the bank that money, but they may write it off depending on the terms of the short sale agreement. However, even if they do it is like partially defaulting on the loan so it will mess up your credit pretty badly. Some say as badly as getting foreclosed on.

The bank agrees to do this when you are clearly in over your head because a foreclosure is a lose-lose scenario in most cases. When the property value has dropped substantially it is definitely a LOSE for the bank. Foreclosing on a house costs them a ton of money and the house value often plummets even further because they will try to make a quick sale to stop the bleeding on holding costs. In many cases the short sale is the lesser of two evils for both you and the lender.

**Short version:** It depends on the short sale agreement, but probably not.

Comment: I would think the bank would still try to get the remainder out of you, even if it was over 30 years for example.

Comment: @xaisoft you should check the State laws, some states explicitly forbid charging house-loan deficiencies in excess of the sale proceeds in case of a short-sale or foreclosure.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in the US, then domestic mortgages are often ["non-recourse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonrecourse_debt), meaning that the bank can seize the collateral (the house) if you default on the mortgage, but they can't come after you for any shortfall if it doesn't sell for the full value of the loan. If you're elsewhere in the world, then they can probably pursue you for the full amount of the loan. But you probably need specialist advice.

Comment: In the US, the recourse vs non-recourse is state to state.  In Oregon for example, it can be either depending how the foreclosure is filed.